# Specify starting row number for \rowcolors from colortbl package

Tags: tables, colortbl

In the following application of `\rowcolors` from the `colortbl` package, how can I specify the option to start the alternating color pattern from the 3rd row onwards?  The first two rows in this case are part of the table heading, so I don't want the alternating background color to begin until the 3rd row down.

If you can, please refer to any relevant sections in the package manual - if it's there I couldn't seem to find it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} %for use in color links
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{Wheat1}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l}
\toprule
        &   \multicolumn{4}{l}{Training data set}   &   Test data set\\
\cmidrule(l r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
Method  &   MSE &   Var(Z)  &   $R^2$   &   RMSE    &   RMSE\\
\cmidrule(r){1 - 1} \cmidrule(l r){2-2} \cmidrule(l r){3-3} \cmidrule(l r){4-4} \cmidrule(l r){5-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6}
Global polynomial, order 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
Global polynomial, order 3 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
Global polynomial, order 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @xport: I notice that the edit here includes UK<->US spellings. I think in general it's best to leave these to the OP. (Other edits perfectly sensible, of course.)

Comment: @Joseph: the first edit, I added 4 ``` to the body but I still needed 2 more characters to be edited. Therefore I am forced to remove 2 `u` from 2 `colour`. Several seconds later, I did the second edit, removing the word "thanks".

Comment: @xport: Fine, it's not a big issue. Just thought I'd mention it as I saw it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first mandatory argument of the `\rowcolor` command indicates the number of the first row which should be colored according to the color scheme given by the second and third mandatory arguments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,x11names,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{5}{}{Wheat1}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l}
  \toprule
  &   \multicolumn{4}{l}{Training data set}   &   Test data set \\
  \cmidrule(l r){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-6} 
  Method  &   MSE &   Var(Z)  &   $R^2$   &   RMSE    &   RMSE\\
  \cmidrule(r){1 - 1} \cmidrule(l r){2-2} \cmidrule(l r){3-3} \cmidrule(l r){4-4} \cmidrule(l r){5-5}   \cmidrule(l){6-6}
  Global polynomial, order 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  Global polynomial, order 3 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
  Global polynomial, order 5 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

EDIT2: or use `\rowcolors{3}{Wheat1}{}` in the above code if you want the first data row to have the `Wheat1` color; in my code, the pattern will start having the first data row with white color.

The `table` option for `xcolor` loads the `colortbl` package, so there's no need to load it separately.

[image]

EDIT: information on the `\rowcolor` command can be found in the `colortbl` documentation and in Section 2.12 *Color in tables* in the `xcolor` documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Gonz.  It worked. :)  I'm just still a little unsure about the \rowcolors arguments and the contents of these arguments, as it isn't really explained explicitly in the manuals.  The first argument is not simply the row number to start the row shading on is it?  If not, then how *is* it defined?  Secondly, I guessed you removed the "white" because it was redundant?