# Command \rowcolors from colortbl does not work as expected

Tags: tables, color

Could someone please explain to me how to apply `\rowcolors`? I found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/specify-starting-row-number-for-rowcolors-from-colortbl-package) but to be honest it does not work for me, not is it well explained in the answer! I could not find description for `\rowcolors` in manual as well. To some extend, input parameters give expected results as below

```
\rowcolors{<row no. to start from}{odd rows colour}{even rows colour}
```

for example: `\row{3}{lightgray!30}{white}` would define 30% of lightgray for all odd rows and white for all even rows starting from 3rd row. But there are examples below where this formula does not work.

I made a MWE below. I was playing with different parameters for `\rowcolors` and I am probably missing something because the results are not what I though they would be.

Let's go through couple of examples where I changed 4th line in the code:

```
\rowcolors{1}{lightgray!30}{} % working
```

[image]

```
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!30} % working
```

[image]

```
\rowcolors{3}{lightgray!30}{} % working
```

[image]

```
% Not working. Colours expected to start from 5th row 
\rowcolors{5}{lightgray!30}{}
```

[image]

```
% Not working. Colours expected to start from 4th row
\rowcolors{4}{}{lightgray!30}
```

[image]

I have an impression `\rowcolors` works only up to third row. Is it a bug or something that I should expect?

Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[usernames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{4}{lightgray!30}{} % To be changed in examples

%\rowcolor{<Start from>}{odd}{even}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r l r l r l r l r }

\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 1}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 2}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 3}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 4}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 & \textbf{H1}
 & \textbf{H2}
 & \textbf{H3}
 & \textbf{H4}
 & \textbf{H5} 
 & \textbf{H6}
 & \textbf{H7}
 & \textbf{H8} \\
\midrule
1 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
2 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
3 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
4 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
5 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
6 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
7 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
8 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\rowcolor[gray]{1}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Extra information} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \cmidrule seems to disturb the count of \rowcolors.

Answer (score 4):

After some tests, the problem seems to come from `\cmidrule`, but it is not specific to `booktabs`, since `\cline` has the same problem.

On the other hand, the row number to start from *must be* an odd number. This means that if you set the starting row number  to be 2, the first grey row will be number 3. So if you really want to start at row number 2, you have to start at number 1 and swap the colours.

Second strange feature: it seems that an odd number of `\cmidrule/\cline`s between two rows counts as a supplementary row. Thus when you want to start at row number 3, you do start at row 3 if you have 0, 2 or 4 \cmidrules, but start at row number 2 if you have 1 or 3.

Here is a code showing these problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usernames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{4}{lightgray!30}{white} % To be changed in examples

%\rowcolor{<Start from>}{odd}{even}

\rowcolors{3}{lightgray!30}{white} % To be changed in examples
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{3}{lightgray!30}{white}
\begin{tabular}{ r l r l r l r l r }

\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 1}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 2}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 3}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 4}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}%
%\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
%\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
%\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 & \textbf{H1}
 & \textbf{H2}
 & \textbf{H3}
 & \textbf{H4}
 & \textbf{H5}
 & \textbf{H6}
 & \textbf{H7}
 & \textbf{H8} \\
\midrule
1 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
2 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
3 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
4 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
5 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
6 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
7 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
8 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\rowcolor[gray]{1}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Extra information} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\rowcolors{3}{lightgray!30}{white}
\begin{tabular}{ r l r l r l r l r }

\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 1}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 2}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 3}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 4}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}%
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
%\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
%\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 & \textbf{H1}
 & \textbf{H2}
 & \textbf{H3}
 & \textbf{H4}
 & \textbf{H5}
 & \textbf{H6}
 & \textbf{H7}
 & \textbf{H8} \\
\midrule
1 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
2 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
3 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
4 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
5 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
6 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
7 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
8 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\rowcolor[gray]{1}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Extra information} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\vspace{1cm}

\rowcolors{3}{lightgray!30}{white}
\begin{tabular}{ r l r l r l r l r }

\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 1}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 2}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 3}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 4}} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}%
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-7}
%\cmidrule(lr){8-9}
 & \textbf{H1}
 & \textbf{H2}
 & \textbf{H3}
 & \textbf{H4}
 & \textbf{H5}
 & \textbf{H6}
 & \textbf{H7}
 & \textbf{H8} \\
\midrule
1 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
2 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
3 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
4 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
5 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
6 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
7 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
8 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\rowcolor[gray]{1}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Extra information} \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tests. At least I know it's not me or my tex distribution. Maybe I should report it as bug.

Comment: I agree with you. Note that you have a workaround, until the bug is fixed.  The problem happens also with `\cline` and, if I remember well, `\hhline`.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has its own command `\rowcolors` which works as expected even when `\cline` or `\cmidrule` (of `booktabs`) are used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ r l r l r l r l r }
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolors{4-10}{lightgray!30}{}[restart]
\Body
    \toprule
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 1}}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 2}}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 3}}
     & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{File 4}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    \cmidrule(lr){6-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-9}
     & \textbf{H1}
     & \textbf{H2}
     & \textbf{H3}
     & \textbf{H4}
     & \textbf{H5} 
     & \textbf{H6}
     & \textbf{H7}
     & \textbf{H8} \\
    \midrule
    1 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    2 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    3 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    4 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    5 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    6 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    7 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    8 & A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{Extra information} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]